# Blocking new signals while in handler

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have a parent process that manages a child (fork, execve). I created a handler in the parent to catch SIGCHLD signals from the child in order to call `waitpid()` and take appropriate action such as restarting the child.

I understood from the manual page for `sigaction()` that, while inside a signal handler, further signals of the same type would be blocked by default. I definitely wish for this behaviour so I decided to test it.

I put a sleep (my own implementation using `clock_nanosleep()` in a loop which resumes when interrupted) at the end of the signal handler and sent a SIGINT to the child. This duly made it quit and sent SIGCHLD to the parent. I logged the fact and started my sleep for 10 seconds. Now, I sent another SIGINT to the new child (sighandler restarted it first time) and was surprised to see another log and sleep happen.

How can this be? When I attached using a debugger to the parent it clearly showed two different threads interrupted to call my signal handler, both now sat in sleep. If that keeps up I will run out of threads!

I understand putting long sleeps into a signal handler is a daft thing to do but it does illustrate the point; I expected to see the second signal marked as pending in /proc/[PID]/status but instead it's delivered.

Here's the relevant bits of my code:

Set up the SIGCHLD handler:

```
typedef struct SigActType {
    struct sigaction act;
    int              retval;
    void             (*func)(int);
}SigActType;
static SigActType sigActList[64];

public void setChildHandler(void (*func)(int)) {
    SigActType *sat = &sigActList[SIGCHLD];

    sat->act.sa_sigaction = sigchldHandler;
    sigemptyset(&sat->act.sa_mask);
    sigaddset (&sat->act.sa_mask, SIGTERM);
    sigaddset (&sat->act.sa_mask, SIGINT);
    sigaddset (&sat->act.sa_mask, SIGCHLD);
    sat->act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sat->retval = 0;
    sat->func = func;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sat->act, NULL);
}

static void sigchldHandler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *thing) {
    SigActType *sat = &sigActList[SIGCHLD];

    if (sat->func) {
        sat->func(si->si_pid);
    }
}
```

and using this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setChildHandler(manageChildSignals);
    ...
}

static void manageChildSignals(int d) {
    if ((pid = waitpid(-1, &stat, WAIT_MYPGRP)) > 0) {
        ... restart child if appropriate
    }
    printf("start of pause...\n");
    mySleep(10);
    printf("end of pause...\n");
}
```

Stdout clearly shows:

```
(when I type kill -2 [PID]
start of pause
(when the new child is started and I type kill -2 [NEWPID]
start of pause
...10 seconds slide past...
end of pause
end of pause
```

I am puzzled as to why this happens. As you can see I even added SIGCHLD to the block mask for `sigaction()` to try to encourage it to do the right thing.

Any pointers most welcome!

Comment: What does `mysleep` do ?

Comment: It is an implementation of `sleep()` using `clock_nanosleep()` in a loop while it returns EINTR so it sleeps the correct amount of time even if interrupted

Comment: Oh, you're using multiple threads.

Comment: Apologies; I should have made that clear. Yes, `main()` sets up signal handlers and worker threads then goes to sleep. The other threads do the work.

Comment: In that case every thread is always eligible to get forced to jump to the signal.

Comment: Clearly, aside from the main one that sets the handlers up in the first place. This may not matter as my concern was a thread in a signal handler could get interrupted by another signal. Two handlers running on two threads should be fine. I assume if every available thread is in a handler any more signals will be pending?

Comment: The main thread can also get the signal.

Comment: Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Don't do complex things (like `printf` or any async-signal-unsafe function) inside a signal handler. Best thing is to set a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag inside signal handlers, and test them outside. See also [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)

Comment: Yes I have done so. But; suppose two children die at once. I will get two signals but I can only set the flag to true. Unless the thread waiting for the flag is very quick it will miss the second instance. In the end I created a pool of threads dedicated to signal handling and blocked signals from all others. I also don't use `printf()`; I put that in the example for clarity. I have my own implementation that logs to a file but I take the point. ps: `signalfd()` looks interesting; I have not come across that before, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> signals of the same type would be blocked by default.

Yes, but only for the thread [`sigaction()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) is called from.

From [`man sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) (**bold** emphasis by me):

> sa_mask specifies a mask of signals which should be blocked (i.e.,
>          added to the signal mask **of the thread in which the signal handler is
>          invoked**) during execution of the signal handler.

As signal dispostion is per process any other thread not blocking the signal in question might receive it, that is get interupted and process it.

If this behaviour is not what you want you should perhaps modify the design of the way your program handles signals in such a way that per default all signals are blocked for each thread, and only one specifiy thread has signal reception unblocked.

**Update:**

Signals masks are inherited from the parent thread by the child thread.

If signal handling shall be done by one specific thread only, have the main thread block all signals prior to creating any other thread. Then create one specfic thread to do the signal handling, and have this thread unblock the signals to be handled. This concept also allows models like one thread per signal.

In a mutlithreaded environment use [`pthread_sigmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html) to mask signals on a per thread base.

Please note that the behaviour of `sigprocmask()` in a multithreaded process is unspecified, use `pthread_sigmask()` then.

Comment: "only for the thread calling sigaction"? That would probably explain it. Any of my other threads may be interrupted to handle this signal then? Just not the 'main' one I called sigaction from?

Comment: Yes indeed. But I think a different thread handling the signal will not cause a problem. I thought `sigaction()` applied to the process!

Comment: For 'update'. Yes, I thought of that and set them back when the child starts.

Comment: @jrichemont: That what is does, the handling is installed for all threads of a process. The maksing however is done for the thread actually receiving a signal. Mask is done on a per thread base. Please see the addtion on pthread_sigmask()` in my answer.